# Evaluate concatenation to text

Tags: excel

I have a Data Validation list in `D4` with numbers 1 to 13. I have the formula `MATCH("ActualYTD"&TEXT(D4,0),[lookup_array],0)`. If `D4` were set to 2, I need the lookup_value in the `MATCH` formula to be `ActualYTD02`. Right now it evaluates to `ActualYTD2`. How do I make it include the zero?

Comment: `TEXT(D4,"00")`?

Comment: @BigBen Thank you. I figured it out as well just after I posted.

Answer (score 1):

...figured it out...

`MATCH("ActualYTD"&TEXT(D4,"00"),[lookup_array],0)`